# Laravel 5 "Class does not exist" when using the scheduler

Tags: dependency-injection, cron, laravel-5

I'm trying to use the scheduler for the first time to call a method:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {   
        $schedule->call('MyClassName@myMethodName')
            ->everyMinute();
    }
```

The class I'm calling is defined in `App/Http/Controller` this way:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Models\Reaction;
use View;
use Request;

class MyClassNameController extends Controller {
```

But each time the scheduler runs, it gaves:

```
  [ReflectionException]
  Class MyClassName does not exist
```

How could I fix this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should not call controller methods this way. Controller methods are meant for handling HTTP requests.

The content of `myMethodName` should be pulled out into a command. You can [learn about creating commands here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/bus#creating-commands).

That aside, the reason you're getting the `ReflectionException` is because of the exact reason the exception states: `MyClassName` is not a valid class.

```
$schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\MyClassNameController@myMethodName')
```

The above specifies the Fully Qualified Name of the class you are trying to refer to. You could alternatively import that class at the top of your file and use a `join`

```
use App\Http\Controllers\MyClassNameController;

// ...

$schedule->call(join('@', [ MyClassNameController::class, 'myMethodName ]))
```

But again, **you should not be calling controller methods this way**.

Comment: Thank you. I don't want to create a CLI command though, I just want to execute a method every minute...

Comment: I'm not suggesting you to create a CLI command. I am suggesting you create a class outside the context of your controller. A class that can be queued, called from the command line, dispatched from within a controller action, or run via the scheduler. Putting this method directly in a controller is not the right way to go about this.

Comment: I see what you mean, I already started making it, and it make perfect sense, thank you