# laravel 5 schedule works with ->cron('* */1 * * *') but doesn't work with ->hourly()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I create a command conttroller, this is my code

```
<?php namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Http\Controllers\AppController;


class UpdData extends Command {

    protected $name = 'upd:data';

    protected $description = 'Update data';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the command.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $app = new AppController;
        $this->info("updated!");
        $app->update_data();
    }
}
```

This is my crontab

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/bin
* * * * * php /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

My `Kernel.php` file

```
<?php namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel {

    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        'App\Console\Commands\Inspire',
        'App\Console\Commands\UpdData',
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // $schedule->command('upd:data')->hourly(); // case 1
        $schedule->command('upd:data')->cron('* */1 * * *'); // case 2
    }
}
```

On the case 1, I try to `php artisan schedule:run`, I get `No scheduled commands are ready to run.` message. On the case 2 it work, but I need to command by myself. **But the two case doesn't not auto run it**. I build my platform on the cloud9, I need your help thanks!

Comment: The [`hourly`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.php#L290) method uses `cron` internally because it's just a helper method, so it should work.

Comment: I had try to use command to call my created. My command will to insert db and it work. But I try to use schedule to call my command, it not work. I have no idea. I sure my cron is work, because I had add a simple touch file on the cron.

Comment: Shouldn't it be  00 */1 * * *  to run hourly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't find the reason, but this code is work for me, if I find the real reason, I will update my answer.

This is work for me, replace `hourly` with `cron`.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('upd:data')->cron('0 * * * *');
}
```