# Laravel 5 call controller action in Kernel schedule

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have controller(testController) and action(index) with in namespace
App\Modules\Admin\Controllers\

I am tring to call action(index) from kernal schedule function in following way

```
$this->call('App\Modules\Admin\Controllers\testController@index')->cron('*/1 * * * *');
```

but action is not getting called. It is throwing an error.

> Error:
>   exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Command "App\Modules\Admin\Controllers\testController@index" is not defined.'

Comment: Solved above issue with help of this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29787696/5356330)

Comment: If you solved either answer your own question or delete it. Don't put solution as comment.